# Object goes invisible when I align it to another object

Tags: modeling

[image][image][image]I’m on the lates version of blender and today I encounter a problem that I myself haven’t been able to resolve trough google searches or simply clicking certain things on and off. Nothing seems to makes sense on why this is happening.

It’s an eyeball object going invisible when I align it wit its other layer of the eye ball. There’s the outer layer the glossy jelly like layer(thin) then there’s the bulk of it the round inside.

When I click transform and align the inner eye ball the bulk of it, too the jelly outer shell, the inner part will go invisible and the ball is now left glass like and there’s no middle or insides in the eye ball, hence it goes invisible and now you can only see the outer (glass bsd). When it’s correct you will be able to see the pupil and eye color and white part of the eye.

Weirdly enough gif I grab the part that’s out of align (the bulk of the eyeball layer) and manually move it inside the outer layer it works BUT it’s not perfectly CENTERED. I need perfect center. I’m new to blender just shy of 2-3 months using it.

My pc build is good ish, i912900k 160 gb ram, rtx 4090.

photos top too bottom order.

the first photo is when i move it manually in place and what its supposed too look like when its correct

the second photo is before tranform align the eye whites down too the glass part.

the last one is when its "aligned" trough the transform align.

Comment: We'll need to see some [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and possibly your Blend file if it's not too large. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page. - Remember that you're the only one who can see what's going on on your computer!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=LY1vGgaq" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LY1vGgaq/)

Comment: What are you actually doing when you say "when I click transform"? The only thing I can see which could cause problems is that the inner eye object has its origin set to the world origin and the outer is set to its geometry. I'm not sure why you didn't just duplicate and scale the outer one to get the inner one in the first place. That way they'd both be in exactly the same place before you started working on them individually!

Comment: Highlight both eye parts, go to object menus,go to transform menu, go down to align. I did duplicate and all that you said, but blender likes to move my stuff randomly hence my current issue, did you download the file and check youreself?

Comment: Yes I did download your file and as I said the origins of the inner and outer eyeballs are in different places, one in the centre of the outer (transparent) eyeball, and the inner one down at the world origin. If you'd duplicated them they should be in the same place. The problem is that setting the inner one to the geometry now will take account of the geometry of the iris and it won't be dead centred relative to the outer.

Comment: Yes after checking you’re 100% right, im having so much trouble remembering the origins and markers. For some reason it won’t stick with me it’s like hard to get around, thank you.